# .htaccess - redirect if site accessed in frame?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, frame

I have two systems, web apps, system A and system B. System A can be accessed either directly or inside a frame from within system B. In the case of the latter, I want to redirect from `page.php` to `page.php?mode=frame` via .htaccess.

Note I am aware of how to do this in JavaScript but I am looking for a .htaccess solution.

This will deny frame access:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

...but can it be modified to redirect rather than deny?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only option you have is to use JavaScript. The presence of a surrounding frame is a client side thing and therefore handling it properly would be limited to client side code.

Keep in mind that interpreting headers would be completely up to the client accessing the site and whatever you put there might simply be ignored.

Comment: +1. Yes, it's up to the client to interpret, but I was thinking that since there is already a means to deny frames via .htaccess, it would be a small step to move to a redirect rather than denial.

Comment: The X-Frame-Options makes the browser deny showing the page requested it is still rendered on the server and transferred over the wire. The server has no idea* that the page is going to render in a frame. *There could be headers like referrals sent to the server that indicates this.